# Location of a packed font to recall in blender python

Tags: python, scripting, text-object, font

I have this simple code that changes the font of the "String to Curves" node in Geometry nodes.

But I want to set the font location to a font I have already packed in the blend file. (Let's say the font is called Oswald-Light.ttf)

I don't know where the location is, and I don't know what to put in the brackets of the data_font location.

````
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
node_group = modifier.node_group
node = node_group.nodes['String to Curves']
data_font = bpy.data.fonts.load('C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Font.ttf')
node.font = data_font

```
````

Comment: if the font is packed then: node.font = bpy.data.fonts["Oswald-Light.ttf"] should do it, no need of a path

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to alambre.

````
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
node_group = modifier.node_group
node = node_group.nodes['String to Curves']
data_font = bpy.data.fonts["Oswald-Light.ttf"]
node.font = data_font
```
````